# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked using Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i had tried to solve this error `ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '0'.` in this way:

**TS:**

```
 import {
     ChangeDetectionStrategy
 } from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
     templateUrl: './page.html'
     changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
 })
 public Pages: Object;

 ngOnInit() {
     loadAllGuides() {
         this.ApiService
             .getAllPages()
             .subscribe(
                 Pages => {
                     this.Pages = Pages.data;
                 }, error => {
                     console.log(error);
                 });
     }
 }
```

When i used `ChangeDetectionStrategy` the error got solved in console but i am facing one more issue, the page is not showing any data unless i give a click when the page opens. Once i give a random click on page the data loads. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Why is `loadAllGuides` inside `ngOnInit` ? When does it get executed then ? All i can see is it implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

First Delete`changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Secondly, you have:
`public Pages:Object;`  => avoid using a First capital letter for variables, so use `public pages:Object;` instead.

then here you have:

```
 Pages => {
    this.Pages = Pages.data;
}
```

try:

```
response => {
    this.pages = response.data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide initial value.

for example -

`public Pages = null;`

for more information read this article - [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4). It explain this error in great detail. Hope it helps.